# form.showdialog then form.close / or form.dispose throws System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a strange problem. Sure many of you have done something similar to form.showdialog() and then close it by Me.Close().
One form has this code.

```
FSettling.CallingForm = "StationPOS"
    FSettling.fText = "Settle Account - Station"
    FSettling.tAmountDue.Text = Me.bTotal.Text
    FSettling.ShowDialog()
    FSettling.Dispose()
```

Next form has this code.

```
Private Sub bSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bSave.Click,
 bCancel.Click
    Dim btn As Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuFlatButton = DirectCast(sender,
 Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuFlatButton)
    btn.selected = False
    Select Case True
        Case sender Is bSave
            saveSettle()
        Case sender Is bCancel
            Me.Close()
    End Select
End Sub
```

I have been using vs 2017 for a short while but this is the first time this has happened and it got me very frustrated.

Comment: Your second code snippet is crazy. The whole point of using a common event handler is that you want to do the same thing for each control. You aren't doing the same thing so there's no point to having a common event handler.  You should have two separate event handlers in that case.

Comment: Is `FSettling` the form type or is it a variable?

Comment: FSettling is the form name.
Sorry for something so crazy. with the snippet. I find bugs easier with things combined :D

Comment: *"I find bugs easier with things combined"*. Then you should get over that because that's bad code. What you do is up to you, of course, but if I was hiring or marking, that code would not be advantageous to you.

Comment: This program I am making is for myself mate :D. Of course I will not write code like that if it was for a client. The next programmer after me would be really pissed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the default instance of the type, which you should not in that case.  Create a form instance yourself, display it and then dispose it, which is best done with a `Using` statement:

```
Using dialogue As New FSettling
    dialogue.ShowDialog()
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks mate. The problem was with the  "BunifuFlatButton". Somehow it throws the error if I close or dispose the form.
I've change the button with the basic button and the problem went away.
But I like how Using clause makes me write less code when closing a form :D